Google Sheets Query or Filter Formula that Sums values based on Column
I'm trying to use a single formula like query or filter to generate a new data table but I'm running into issues due to multiple lines for the same customer and needing to sum Quantity and Amount columns. I am needing the final table to not repeat any customers but also sum the values if it's the same customer. Any help here would be greatly appreciated!
Example data - Note the two lines for CUSTOMER4



Name
Source
Location
2024-01 Qty
2024-01 Amt
2024-02 Qty
2024-02 Amt
2024-03 Qty
2024-03 Amt




CUSTOMER1
Web
LocationA
60
$3,000.00
20
$1,000.00
4
$200.00


CUSTOMER2
Web
LocationA


35
$1,750.00

$0.00


CUSTOMER3
Store
LocationA
10
$500.00
50
$2,500.00
15
$750.00


CUSTOMER4
Store
LocationA
32
$1,600.00
41
$2,050.00
62
$3,100.00


CUSTOMER5
Store
LocationA
5
$250.00


13
$650.00


CUSTOMER4
Store
LocationB
12
$600.00
74
$3,700.00
43
$2,150.00



Desired outcome if wanting to only look at Store data regardless of the location. Note that CUSTOMER4 values are added together.



Name
Source
2024-01 Qty
2024-01 Amt
2024-02 Qty
2024-02 Amt
2024-03 Qty
2024-03 Amt




CUSTOMER3
Store
10
$500.00
50
$2,500.00
15
$750.00


CUSTOMER4
Store
44
$2,200.00
115
$5,750.00
105
$5,250.00


CUSTOMER5
Store
5
$250.00


13
$650.00




you can use pivot tables for this. use SUM for all columns you need. see https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop

Let's assume A1:I7 is your data range and Source at column B, then you can use following formula to query Source = "Store"
={A1:B1, D1:I1; query(A2:I7,"select A,B,sum(D),sum(E),sum(F),sum(G),sum(H),sum(I) where B='Store' group by A,B label sum(D)'',sum(E)'',sum(F)'',sum(G)'',sum(H)'',sum(I)''")}

Works perfectly, thanks!
